# hadoop, how to include 3part jar while try to run mapred job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, classpath

As we know, new need to pack all needed class into the job-jar and upload it to server. it's so slow, i will to know whether there is a way which to specify the thirdpart jar include executing map-red job, so that i could only pack my classes with out dependencies.

PS(i found there is a "-libjar" command, but i doesn't figure out how to use it. Here is the link http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2011/01/how-to-include-third-party-libraries-in-your-map-reduce-job/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are called [generic options](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.0/commands_manual.html#Generic+Options). 
So, to support those, your job should implement Tool.

Run your job like --

```
hadoop jar yourfile.jar [mainClass] args -libjars <comma seperated list of jars>
```

Edit:

To implement *Tool* and extend *Configured*, you do something like this in your MapReduce application --

```
public class YourClass extends Configured implements Tool {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
         int res = ToolRunner.run(new YourClass(), args);
         System.exit(res);
      }

      public int run(String[] args) throws Exception
      {
        //parse you normal arguments here.

        Configuration conf = getConf();
        Job job = new Job(conf, "Name of job");

        //set the class names etc

        //set the output data type classes etc

        //to accept the hdfs input and outpur dir at run time
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        return job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is my command "[admin1@tisrv01 workspace]$ hadoop jar ttcnClearness-1.0.0-snapshot.jar  /user/zhouuyud/input/input/ns30triplexs-2013-09-11--1633.bz2 /user/zhouuyud/output/ -libjars ../workspace/lib/*.jar".    But, i got a exception, because in main main method, i will check the args length, the -libjars xxxx were passed to main main method. Is it right?

Comment: You don't need to handle -libjars option yourself, ToolRunner would do that for you and filter out Hadoop related options as included in the link Generic options above. Added code to show how to implement Tool and Extend Configured.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to specify -libjar option before the arguments. Otherwise it was considered as an argument.