# How to run examples in mahout in action book

Tags: java, eclipse, hadoop, jar, mahout

I am trying to run the hello world example in chapter 7. I created the following in eclipse and then packed it into a jar:-

```
package com.mycode.mahout
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.mahout.clustering.WeightedVectorWritable;
import org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.Cluster;
import org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver;
import org.apache.mahout.common.distance.EuclideanDistanceMeasure;
import org.apache.mahout.math.RandomAccessSparseVector;
import org.apache.mahout.math.Vector;
import org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable;

public class SimpleKMeansClustering {
  public static final double[][] points = { {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {1, 2},
                                           {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {8, 8},
                                           {9, 8}, {8, 9}, {9, 9}};

  public static void writePointsToFile(List<Vector> points,
                                       String fileName,
                                       FileSystem fs,
                                       Configuration conf) throws IOException {
    Path path = new Path(fileName);
    SequenceFile.Writer writer = new SequenceFile.Writer(fs, conf,
        path, LongWritable.class, VectorWritable.class);
    long recNum = 0;
    VectorWritable vec = new VectorWritable();
    for (Vector point : points) {
      vec.set(point);
      writer.append(new LongWritable(recNum++), vec);
    }
    writer.close();
  }

  public static List<Vector> getPoints(double[][] raw) {
    List<Vector> points = new ArrayList<Vector>();
    for (int i = 0; i < raw.length; i++) {
      double[] fr = raw[i];
      Vector vec = new RandomAccessSparseVector(fr.length);
      vec.assign(fr);
      points.add(vec);
    }
    return points;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    int k = 2;

    List<Vector> vectors = getPoints(points);

    File testData = new File("testdata");
    if (!testData.exists()) {
      testData.mkdir();
    }
    testData = new File("testdata/points");
    if (!testData.exists()) {
      testData.mkdir();
    }

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
    writePointsToFile(vectors, "testdata/points/file1", fs, conf);

    Path path = new Path("testdata/clusters/part-00000");
    SequenceFile.Writer writer = new SequenceFile.Writer(fs, conf,
        path, Text.class, Cluster.class);

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
      Vector vec = vectors.get(i);
      Cluster cluster = new Cluster(vec, i, new EuclideanDistanceMeasure());
      writer.append(new Text(cluster.getIdentifier()), cluster);
    }
    writer.close();

    KMeansDriver.run(conf, new Path("testdata/points"), new Path("testdata/clusters"),
      new Path("output"), new EuclideanDistanceMeasure(), 0.001, 10,
      true, false);

    SequenceFile.Reader reader = new SequenceFile.Reader(fs,
        new Path("output/" + Cluster.CLUSTERED_POINTS_DIR
                 + "/part-m-00000"), conf);

    IntWritable key = new IntWritable();
    WeightedVectorWritable value = new WeightedVectorWritable();
    while (reader.next(key, value)) {
      System.out.println(value.toString() + " belongs to cluster "
                         + key.toString());
    }
    reader.close();
  }

}
```

I packed it as myjob.jar

now how shall I execute this on my cluster ?

I tried following:-

```
hadoop jar myjob.jar com.mycode.mahout.SimpleKMeansClustering 
java -jar myjob.jar
java -cp myjob.jar
```

I get follwing error:-

```
 [root@node1 tmp]# hadoop jar mahoutfirst.jar com.mahout.emc.SimpleKMeansClustering 
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:         org/apache/mahout/math/Vector`
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:201)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.math.Vector
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 3 more
```

Please advice what is the right way to run the code written using mahout.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this pretty late but I was facing similar issues and following approach does work for me as i don't wanted to use maven:

1) Go to your mahout installation directory & look for *job.jar as

```
ls /usr/lib/mahout/
conf  lib       mahout-core-0.5-cdh3u3-job.jar  mahout-examples-0.5-cdh3u3-job.jar  mahout-taste-webapp-0.5-cdh3u3.war
```

2) Copy mahout-examples-0.5-cdh3u3-job.jar to the directory where code resides

3) Use the "job" JAR file provided by Mahout. It packages up all the dependencies. You need to add your classes to it too. As you have compiled your class using hadoop and mahout libraries you have your .class file ready.

4) Add your class file to the job jar  mahout-core-0.5-cdh3u3-job.jar in your directory:

```
jar uf mahout-core-0.5-cdh3u3-job.jar SimpleKMeansClustering.class
```

4) Run the hadoop jar as using your code:

```
hadoop jar mahout-core-0.5-cdh3u3-job.jar  SimpleKMeansClustering
```

5) At the end of your map-reduce job you can see:

```
1.0: [1.000, 1.000] belongs to cluster 0
1.0: [2.000, 1.000] belongs to cluster 0
1.0: [1.000, 2.000] belongs to cluster 0
1.0: [2.000, 2.000] belongs to cluster 0
1.0: [3.000, 3.000] belongs to cluster 0
1.0: [8.000, 8.000] belongs to cluster 1
1.0: [9.000, 8.000] belongs to cluster 1
1.0: [8.000, 9.000] belongs to cluster 1
1.0: [9.000, 9.000] belongs to cluster 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the not class definition found exception above, it seems you probably need to include the Mahout related jars (mahout-core.jar, I guess) with your Hadoop job.

To pass the jars to mappers throughout the cluster, you need to probably make use of DistributedCache or the `-libjar` Hadoop option. The idea for the latter is [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029760/hadoop-how-to-include-3part-jar-while-try-to-run-mapred-job/19033328#19033328).