# Running Kmeans Clustering example with Maven (Mahout in Action)

Tags: maven, cluster-analysis, k-means, mahout

I'm considering the same example as in [How to run examples in mahout in action book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19388769/how-to-run-examples-in-mahout-in-action-book), but I want to use Maven to run it.  It builds fine with

```
> mvn clean -DskipTests package
```

but when I try to run it:

```
> java -cp target/K-Means-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar Clustering.Kmeans


Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/apache/mahout/math/Vector
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at 
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at 
sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.math.Vector
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

This is strange, since I included mahout-math-0.7 in my pom.xml, and I manually checked that it includes Vector.class.  So what's going wrong?  Do I need to use hadoop rather than java, or is there something wrong with my pom.xml?  I'm assuming that having http://maven.apache.org is fine if I'm pulling from http://mvnrepository.com/ ...

For reference, here's what I have in my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>Clustering</groupId>
<artifactId>K-Means</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>K-Means</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
     <artifactId>mahout-mr</artifactId>
     <version>0.10.0</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
        <artifactId>mahout-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.mahout</groupId>
        <artifactId>mahout-math</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

And here are my imports:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.mahout.clustering.Cluster;
import org.apache.mahout.clustering.classify.WeightedPropertyVectorWritable;
import org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver;
import org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.Kluster;
import org.apache.mahout.common.distance.EuclideanDistanceMeasure;
import org.apache.mahout.math.RandomAccessSparseVector;
import org.apache.mahout.math.Vector;
import org.apache.mahout.math.VectorWritable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
```

Answer (score 0):

You classpath doesn't include all the jars.

Also don't mix versions.

Comment: Then where are the jars located, if they aren't packaged into the one I included?

Comment: Check the jar size and contents. In fact, merging everything into one big jar may be next to impossible (because of duplicate file names, so you will also need to merge some files). There are maven plugins to help you get required jars and a launch script.

Comment: But note that Mahout kmeans is horribly slow. Rather use e.g. ELKI instead which is much faster.