# How to compile a java source file with multiple external jar?

Tags: java, json, hadoop

I have a hadoop application. I write a java program which needs org.json.jar package as well as hadoop-core.jar. I compile this source file with the following linux command.

```
mkdir q3_classes
javac -classpath ${HADOOP_HOME}/hadoop-core.jar:${HADOOP_HOME}/org.json-20120521.jar -d q3_classes ETLQ3.java
jar -cvf q3.jar -C q3_classes/ .
```

It compiles successfully. But when I run this program with the following command. (The same command applies to WordCount example successfully.)

```
hadoop jar q3.jar MainClassName /input /output
```

It throws ClassNotFound exception. The org.json.object class cannot be found.

So I wonder is there anything wrong in my compile command? How to compile the java source file with these two jar packages?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you do not have the JAR on your classpath. Add them to your classpath.

Comment: Thanks. Could you tell me how to do this?

Comment: @user3023526 From your example you do *seem* to have the jar in your classpath. is your `HADOOP_HOME` pointing properly ?

Comment: Yes. Because I run WordCount using the same command without org.json.jar. It runs correctly.

Comment: Try adding the classes to the `java` classpath as `java -cp /your/class/path` and see if that helps. Whatever classpath you have for `javac`, add it for `java`

Comment: But I want the job run on hadoop cluster. How to do that?

Comment: @Duran Well.. I do not have a clue about that. Looks like you will have to wait for a more experienced person to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You jar `org.json-20120521.jar` probably needs to be sent to all the nodes of the cluster. Try using the --libjars option

hadoop jar q3.jar MainClassName /input /output --libJars org.json-20120521.jar

Make sure you following what said [here in the edit part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19029760/hadoop-how-to-include-3part-jar-while-try-to-run-mapred-job/19033328#19033328) to how to actually write your MapReduce application.